# Maven class post-processing

Tags: java, maven, maven-plugin, aggregate

I developed a maven plugin with @aggregator annotation.

If I run

```
mvn clean compile my:artifact:task package
```

then it compiles 2 times.

So I insert this fragment into my pom

```
<plugin>
   <groupId>my</groupId>
   <artifactId>artifact</artifactId>
   <version>1.0.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
   <executions>
       <execution>
           <id>post-classes</id>
           <phase>process-classes</phase>
           <goals>
              <goal>task</goal>
           </goals>
      </execution>
   </executions>
</plugin>
```

but then it will run on each module (@ aggregator is seemingly ignored).

How do I let the plugin run once after compiling?

**Edit:**
My problem refers to the default lifecycle of eclipse tycho. But there is an [major bug](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=388909) so I was very confused.

Comment: where is the plugin defined? In the child module or the parent module?

Comment: `@aggregator` annotation, if I remember correctly, makes your plugin goal run only once for your whole project.

Comment: @Kata I added this xml snippet in the parent pom

Comment: @Andrew thats the behavior I expected, but it works only if I compile it twice

Comment: Are you referencing it in the child poms?

Comment: No I don't, should I?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From [this](http://docs.codehaus.org/display/MAVEN/Aggregator+Plugins):

> For mojos executed directly from the CLI, the mojo will only be executed once and not per each project in the reactor. For mojos bound to a lifecycle phase, the mojo will be executed for each project where the lifecycle binding is present.

You have two options:

- If you insist on using the aggregator annotation: remove the lifecycle binding and run it via command line, such as "mvn clean compile my:artifact:task jar:jar". Similar to [assembly:assembly](http://www.sonatype.com/books/mvnref-book/reference/assemblies-sect-basics.html) which is designed to be invoked directly from the command line, and should never be bound to a build lifecycle phase.
- If you insist on binding your plugin to lifecycle, remove the aggregator annotation and follow this [article](http://www.sonatype.com/people/2009/05/how-to-make-a-plugin-run-once-during-a-build/). The idea is to examine the project properties where maven is *currently* running on.

Comment: How do I ensure that my plugin is executed after compiling, but before packaging?

Comment: @Nachtgold, change "mvn clean compile my:artifact:task package" to "mvn clean compile my:artifact:task jar:jar" if you are expecting a jar packaging.

Comment: Attach it to the `prepare-package` phase.

Comment: I have read the sonar article very often, but the final idea I missed, was the `prepare-package` phase. And using `jar:jar` instead of the `package` lifecycle is also perfect. Thank you both!